# Test for filtering sensitive information (params) in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, testing, sanitization, acceptance-testing

I have a Rails 3.0.x app that I changed the credit card number that was submitted via a form. Before I made the change, the filtering was set up correctly and was filtering the number:

```
grep 'parameters' config/application.rb 
config.filter_parameters += [:password, :password_confirmation, :sin, :credit_card_number, :verification_value]
```

I changed the name of the field and the number was no longer filtered... however, no test caught this.

Is there a simple way to verify that my parameter filtering is working in my automated tests? We use shoulda and testunit, if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Shoulda has a controller matcher for this:

```
should filter_param(:credit_card_number)
```

Comment: Yeah, but I've changed the parameter in the model, so this wouldn't catch the error.